# Data is not written to Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My script copies "unread" incoming messages from mail from the marked folder to the google table, and then marks it as read. But sometimes there are failures: the script is executed, marks the letters "as read", but does not write to the table. That is, in fact, it turns out in the logger there is a record with all the contents of these letters, but they are not written to the table. In theory, you need to check whether the data was written to the table and only then mark the letters "as read". Maybe there is an error in the code that periodically makes itself felt?  Guys, help me, I'm just learning.

```
        function GmailmarkReadEnd() {
  
  //this is just the stuff that recognizes what spreadsheet you're in
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Лист2'); //gets the right sheet
  
  /* searches your GMail for emails matching things "label:unread" + " label:support"
  */
  var query = "label:unread" + " label:support"; 
  
  var threads = GmailApp.search(query);
  
  var supportStats = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
    
    for (var m = 0; m < messages.length; m++) {
      var from = messages[m].getFrom(); //from field
      var to = messages[m].getTo(); //to field
      var time = messages[m].getDate(); //date field
      var subject = messages[m].getSubject(); //subject field
      var body = messages[m].getPlainBody(); //body field
      var mId = messages[m].getId(); //id field to create the link later
      
      if (query === "label:unread" + " label:support") {
        supportStats.push([from,to,time,subject,body,'https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/'+mId]);
        Logger.log(supportStats) // The log about which he spoke.
      }
      
    }
  }
  if(!threads.length) return; //  if there are no unread ones, do nothing.
  sheet.getRange(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastRow()+1,2,supportStats.
                 length,supportStats[0].length).setValues(supportStats); //writes to the spreadsheet
  
  GmailApp.markThreadsRead(threads); // marks as read
  
  // ***Sorting Recorded Data by Date***
  sheet.getRange('D:D').activate();
  sheet.sort(4, false);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add the textual error to your question

Comment: Hello Rubén. Thank. I recently became interested in programming.
You can clarify where to see the text error?
There are no errors in the execution log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who helped. If anything, read the comments.

```
function GmailmarkReadEnd() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Лист2'); //gets the right sheet
  const query = "label:unread" + " label:support"; 
  var threads = GmailApp.search(query);
  var supportStats = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
    for (var m = 0; m < messages.length; m++) {
      var from = messages[m].getFrom(); //from field
      var to = messages[m].getTo(); //to field
      var time = messages[m].getDate(); //date field
      var subject = messages[m].getSubject(); //subject field
      var body = messages[m].getPlainBody(); //body field
      var mId = messages[m].getId(); //id field to create the link later
      supportStats.push([from,to,time,subject,body,'https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/'+mId]);
      Logger.log(supportStats) // The log about which he spoke.
    }
  }
  if(!threads.length) return; //  if there are no unread ones, do nothing.
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1,2,supportStats.length,supportStats[0].length).setValues(supportStats); //writes to the spreadsheet
  GmailApp.markThreadsRead(threads); // marks as read
  sheet.sort(4, false);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function GmailmarkReadEnd() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Лист2'); //gets the right sheet
  const query = "label:unread" + " label:support"; 
  var threads = GmailApp.search(query);
  var supportStats = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
    for (var m = 0; m < messages.length; m++) {
      var from = messages[m].getFrom(); //from field
      var to = messages[m].getTo(); //to field
      var time = messages[m].getDate(); //date field
      var subject = messages[m].getSubject(); //subject field
      var body = messages[m].getPlainBody(); //body field
      var mId = messages[m].getId(); //id field to create the link later
      supportStats.push([from,to,time,subject,body,'https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/'+mId]);
      Logger.log(supportStats) // The log about which he spoke.
    }
  }
  if(!threads.length) return; //  if there are no unread ones, do nothing.
  sheet.getRange(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastRow()+1,2,supportStats.length,supportStats[0].length).setValues(supportStats); //writes to the spreadsheet
  GmailApp.markThreadsRead(threads); // marks as read
  sheet.sort(4,false);
}
```

Comment: Hi Cooper.
Thanks for the help. Now I will test.
At the moment there is an error related to sorting by column: Exception: Unable to convert "[object Object]" to int. (line 23). Maybe you should return the old version ?:  ``` sheet.getRange ('D: D'). Activate ();
sheet.sort (4, false); ``` - it works.

Comment: That's a new command.  I should have looked it up.  sorry.  But I don't think this `sheet.getRange ('D: D'). Activate ()` does anything.

Comment: But oddly enough, without `sheet.getRange ('D: D'). Activate ();`, the row `sheet.sort (4, false);`–does not work.

Comment: Tested your version of the code. It got better, thanks. Another reason was found out: the data in the table was written on top of the existing ones. For example, the table contains 10 rows, and if there are 3 rows in the array, then the first three rows in the table were replaced with rows from the array. The question was solved by replacing:`sheet.getRange(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastRow()+1,2,supportStats.length,supportStats[0].length).setValues(supportStats);`on`sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1,2,supportStats.length,supportStats[0].length).setValues(supportStats);`